# Odd length diagonal string pattern

Tags: java, string, diagonal

I have written a program to print the given string diagonally (like x)

Input: `PROGRAM`

Expected output:

```
P     M
 R   A
  O R
   G
  O R
 R   A
P     M
```

My output:

```
P
       M
 R
      A
  O
     R
       G
    R
   O
     A
  R
      M
 P
```

My Java class:

```
import java.util.*;

class Codechef
{

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = in.nextLine();
        char[] word = new char[100];
        word = s.toCharArray();
        int count=0;
        int k = s.length()-1;

        for (int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
            for (int j=0;j<s.length();j++){
               if(!(i==k))
                   System.out.println(word[i]);

               for(int x=0;x<s.length()-count;x++)
                   System.out.print(" ");

               System.out.println(word[k]);
               k--;
               count++;

               break; 
            }

            for(int j=0;j<count;j++)
                System.out.print(" ");    
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: *what is wrong in my code*: that's what you are supposed to tell us: what you expect the code to do, precisely, with example inputs and outputs, and what it does instead, precisely.

Comment: I need output like this http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-string-of-odd-length-in-x-format/

Comment: Put that crucial information, as properly formatted text (using a code block), in the question itself. Then answer the rest of my questions, still by editing your question.

Comment: I fail to understand your logic. Here's a hint: At row 0, you must print the letters at index 0 and k of the word. All the other indices stay blank. At row 1, you must print the letters at index 1 and k - 1 of the word. All the other indices stay blank. At row 2, you must print the letters at index 2 and k - 2 of the word. All the other indices stay blank. My whole algorithm, properly indented, fits in 11 lines of code.

Comment: But can be reduced and still be readable in 6 lines of code.

Comment: @Sudarsan You can store that output in a matrix of characters (or in a vector of strings) and then print it. That should be easier. Just ''print'' one word at a time.

Comment: What is wrong with your code, frankly, it’s first and most importantly (I mean this) that it’s next to impossible for an outsider to understand your logic. If we were able to understand, we’d also be able to assist in fixing the output. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic works only upper part of Horizontal line. 
Go through the below Program:

```
import java.util.*;

class Codechef
{

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = in.nextLine();
        char[] word = new char[100];
        word = s.toCharArray();
        int k = s.length()-1;
        int x ;

        for (int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
               if((i<k))
               {
                   for (x=0; x<i; x++)
                       System.out.print(" ");
                   System.out.print(word[i]);
                   for ( x=0; x<k-i-1; x++)
                       System.out.print(" ");
                   System.out.println(word[k]);
                   k--;

               }

               else if(i == k){
                   for ( x=0; x<i; x++)
                       System.out.print(" ");
                   System.out.println(word[k]);
                   k--;

               }
               else{
                   for(x = k; x >= 0 ; x--)
                       System.out.print(" ");
                   System.out.print(word[k]);
                   for (x=0; x<i-k-1; x++)
                       System.out.print(" ");
                   System.out.println(word[i]);
                   k--;

               }

            }

    }

}
```

It gives output as you saying.

Answer (score 0):

The simpler way to print this pattern could be as suggested by [BlackArrow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7555119/black-arrow), we can store the pattern in 2-D array and then print it gracefully.The code is as follows:-

```
public static void printDiagonalPattern(String str) {
    int len = str.length();
    //if length is even, then pattern is not possible.
    if (len % 2 == 0) {
        return;
    } else {

        char[][] matrix = new char[len][len];
        char[] givenString = str.toCharArray();
        //prepare elements for first diagonal i.e. up to down.
        for (int i = 0, j=0; i<len && j< len; i++, j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = givenString[i];
        }
        //prepare elements for second diagonal i.e. down to up.
        for (int i = len-1, j=0; i>=0 && j< len; i--, j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = givenString[j];
        }
        for(int i = 0; i<len; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j<len; j++) {
                System.out.print(matrix[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go through below program,

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrintWelcome {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter odd string only :");
        String s=sc.nextLine();
        char c[]=s.toCharArray();
        int len=c.length;
        if((len&1)==0)
            System.out.println("string is prime: ");
        else{
            System.out.println("String is : "+s.trim()+", length : "+len);
            System.out.println("String center letter is : "+c[len/2]);
            int i, j=0,k,n=c.length/2,m=n+1;
            int last=c.length-1;
            int l=c.length-1;
            //upper portion 
            for(i=0; i<=c.length/2; i++)
            {   
                //if(n>=0)
                //upper center spaces
                for(j=c.length/2;j>i; j--)
                {
                    System.out.print(" ");//upper center spaces
                }//upper left array values
                for(k=i;k<=i;k++)
                {
                    System.out.print(c[n]);//upper left array values
                    n--;
                }
                //}
                //upper right part spaces
                if(m<=c.length-1)
                {
                    for(j=1; j<i*2; j++)
                    {
                        System.out.print(" ");//up
                    }//upper right values
                    for(k=m;k<=i+(c.length/2);k++)
                    {
                        System.out.print(c[m]);
                        m++;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println();
            }

            //below pattern
            for (int x = 0; x <=c.length/2; x++) {
                //below right spaces
                for(int y=1;y<=x;y++)
                {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                //below left values
                for(int z=x;z<=x;z++)
                {
                    System.out.print(c[z]);
                }
                //below center space            
                for(int p=j-2;p>=x*2;p--)
                {
                    System.out.print(" ");

                }
                //below right values
                if(last>c.length/2)
                {
                    for(int r=last;r<=l;r++)
                    {
                        System.out.print(c[r]);
                        l--;
                        last--;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: This solution prints a diamond... Did you read the question correctly?